I would like to improve performance for my Snowflake SQL query that contains a Well-Known Text (WKT)
I have a Snowflake query that contains a Well-Known Text (WKT) and I'm trying to improve the performance.
WITH CustomArea AS (
    SELECT 
        "PPPPPP" AS GC,
        ROUND(SUM(HP),5) AS HP,
        ROUND(SUM(PP),5) AS PP  
    FROM 
        "DB1"."SCHEMA1"."TABLE1"
    WHERE 
        ST_WITHIN (CE, TO_GEOGRAPHY('POLYGON ((...))'))
    GROUP BY 
        GC
),
FilteredData AS (
    SELECT
        tbl.VC,
        CASE
            WHEN tbl.WU = 'PP' THEN a.PP * tbl.VV
            WHEN tbl.WU = 'HH' THEN a.HP * tbl.VV
            ELSE tbl.VV
        END AS Count
    FROM 
        "DB2"."SCHEMA2"."TABLE2" tbl
    INNER JOIN 
        CustomArea a ON tbl.CC = a.GC 
    WHERE 
        tbl.GG = 'PPPPPP'
    AND 
        tbl.VC IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
)
SELECT
    VC,
    SUM(Count) AS Count
FROM 
    FilteredData
GROUP BY 
    VC;

"DB1"."SCHEMA1"."TABLE1" INFO:

Cluster by: N/A




Columns
Data Type




KE
VARCHAR(14)


GI
NUMBER(38,0)


GO
VARCHAR(14)


HP
NUMBER(18,8)


PP
NUMBER(18,8)


FL
VARCHAR(6)


PPPPPP
VARCHAR(8)


PA
VARCHAR(8)


CT
VARCHAR(16)


CA
VARCHAR(16)


PC
VARCHAR(16)


PS
VARCHAR(16)


PF
VARCHAR(16)


PR
VARCHAR(2)


RR
VARCHAR(1)


CN
VARCHAR(2)


FQ
VARCHAR(16)


CE
GEOGRAPHY



"DB2"."SCHEMA2"."TABLE2" INFO:

Cluster by: LINEAR(GG, YY, SC)




Columns
Data Type




CC
VARCHAR(1000)


GG
VARCHAR(1024)


GI
NUMBER(10,0)


NN
VARCHAR(16777216)


VC
VARCHAR(16777216)


YY
VARCHAR(1024)


SC
NUMBER(38,5)


VV
FLOAT


WU
VARCHAR(255)



Snowflake Query Explain Plan:
{
    "GlobalStats": {
        "partitionsTotal": 1085,
        "partitionsAssigned": 183,
        "bytesAssigned": 2916814336
    },
    "Operations": [
        [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "operation": "Result",
                "expressions": [
                    "tbl.VC",
                    "SUM(IFF(tbl.WU = 'PP', (TO_DOUBLE(ROUND(SUM(TABLE1.PP), 5))) * tbl.VV, IFF(tbl.WU = 'HH', (TO_DOUBLE(ROUND(SUM(TABLE1.HP), 5))) * tbl.VV, tbl.VV)))"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "operation": "Aggregate",
                "expressions": [
                    "aggExprs: [SUM(IFF(tbl.WU = 'PP', (TO_DOUBLE(ROUND(SUM(TABLE1.PP), 5))) * tbl.VV, IFF(tbl.WU = 'HH', (TO_DOUBLE(ROUND(SUM(TABLE1.HP), 5))) * tbl.VV, tbl.VV)))]",
                    "groupKeys: [tbl.VC]"
                ],
                "parentOperators": [
                    0
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "operation": "InnerJoin",
                "expressions": [
                    "joinKey: (TABLE1.PPPPPP = tbl.CC)"
                ],
                "parentOperators": [
                    1
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "operation": "Aggregate",
                "expressions": [
                    "aggExprs: [SUM(TABLE1.HP), SUM(TABLE1.PP)]",
                    "groupKeys: [TABLE1.PPPPPP]"
                ],
                "parentOperators": [
                    2
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "operation": "Filter",
                "expressions": [
                    "ST_CONTAINS_LNGLAT_ROUND(TO_BINARY(GET(IFF(PARSE_GEO('POLYGON ((...))') IS NULL, null, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('_shape', PARSE_GEO('POLYGON ((...))'), 'version', 1, 'has_internal', TRUE, 'internal', GEOGRAPHY_COMPUTE_INTERNAL(PARSE_GEO('POLYGON ((...))')))), 'internal')), TO_BINARY(GET_PATH(TABLE1.CE, 'internal')))"
                ],
                "parentOperators": [
                    3
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "operation": "TableScan",
                "objects": [
                    "DB1.SCHEMA1.TABLE1"
                ],
                "expressions": [
                    "HP",
                    "PP",
                    "PPPPPP"
                ],
                "partitionsAssigned": 3,
                "partitionsTotal": 3,
                "bytesAssigned": 48081920,
                "parentOperators": [
                    4
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "operation": "Filter",
                "expressions": [
                    "(tbl.VC IN 'ABC' IN 'DEF' IN 'GHI') AND (tbl.GG = 'PPPPPP')"
                ],
                "parentOperators": [
                    2
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "operation": "JoinFilter",
                "expressions": [
                    "joinKey: (TABLE1.PPPPPP = tbl.CC)"
                ],
                "parentOperators": [
                    6
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "operation": "TableScan",
                "objects": [
                    "DB2.SCHEMA2.TABLE2"
                ],
                "expressions": [
                    "CC",
                    "GG",
                    "VC",
                    "VV",
                    "WU"
                ],
                "alias": "tbl",
                "partitionsAssigned": 180,
                "partitionsTotal": 1082,
                "bytesAssigned": 2868732416,
                "parentOperators": [
                    7
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}

How do I improve the performance of this query?

Hi - as a general point, please format your data as tables, not bullets, so it is easier to read/copy. Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query

@NickW I have formatted my data as tables and updated my question with the Snowflake Query Profile and Explain Plan in JSON format, thank you.

As it is the scan of "DB2"."SCHEMA2"."TABLE2" that is taking the most time, I'd have a look at optimising that part of the query first. It's not immediately obvious, to me, how to improve it but maybe move the initial select from that table to a CTE and include the filters on CC, GG or both - and see what that does. It may nudge Snowflake to prune partitions more effectively - depends how much you filters reduce the size of the dataset. It may be the only solution is to increase the size of the warehouse - even though that should be a last resort

How long is this query taking to execute?

@NickW I have updated the query and moved the initial select from TABLE2 to a CTE. The times are similar. I have updated the Snowflake Query Execution Plan above, thank you.

@Kathmandude The query is taking around 5 seconds to execute but I want to try and get it under 2 seconds.

@jen How much of that is compilation vs execution time? Also, what sized warehouse are you using?

@Kathmandude Total Duration 4.77s, Queuing 132ms, Compilation 87ms, Execution 4.55s. I am using XS warehouse.

I see that you're only using one of the cluster key columns in your where clause. Assuming the cluster key wasn't created specifically for this query, 7 seconds is really not worth optimizing here, especially for an XS warehouse scanning ~200 partitions. You're scanning <20% of total partitions, which is quite decent. If you run that on say a medium warehouse, and see similar execution times, then I would worry about performance.
